# Xml parsing for soap response

Tags: iphone, ipad

```
how to parse soap response data

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
     <SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
          xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
          xmlns:sqltypes=
           "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/2001/12/SOAP/types" 
           xmlns:sqlmessage=
             "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/2001/12/SOAP/
              types/SqlMessage" 
            xmlns:sqlresultstream=
             "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/2001/12/SOAP/types
              /SqlResultStream" 
            xmlns:tns="http://server/nwind2/soap"
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <tns:MethodNameResponse>
          <tns:OutputParam>Error Code 1152</tns:OutputParam> 
        </tns:MethodNameResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
      </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I expected the response data will be simple xml format, but the response is in soap-env.

how to parse the soap envelop xml data?

Is in soap-envelop format xml parsing is same has simple xml data parse?

**example:Simple XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
         <error >Error Code 1152 </error>
```

@all Any one advice me how to parse this kind on xml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wsdl web services. You can use

```
  http://sudzc.com/
```

which will generate Objective C stubs for you.

Comment: generate Objective C stubs   http://sudzc.com/ and WSDL2Obj tool also generate stubs, But if response data from server in soap-env format how to parse that soap-evn format data?

Comment: You might have passed some wrong parameters. It is showing some error. Have you tried with other web services which returning no error and response comes in this format?

Comment: i want to parse that error message! and display it on my console... "Error Code 1152" That is my requirement

Comment: Have you tried with sudzc? It will automatically parse SoapFault or Error in its call back function for you.

Comment: @ spaleja with sudzc it create the classes for the given url! that is call stubs for the web services.  Include the classes into the application and pass the parameter to the method to invoke the request!  for the response it giving error i want to parse that error and display into alert box!